# Proving that choice holds in $V_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha$

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

The following is a well known result

**Theorem:** the axioms of $\textsf{ZFC}$ hold at (and above) the following levels of the von Neumann hierarchy:

1. all levels (i.e. $V_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha \in \text{On}$): extensionality, foundation, union, choice, separation;
2. limit ordinals: powerset, pairs;
3. ordinals greater than $\omega$: infinity;
4. at [worldly](http://cantorsattic.info/Worldly) cardinals: replacement.

It wasn't clear to me how we ought to show this for choice. (Note the version of choice assumed here is important; I take the 'choice set' version rather than the 'choice function', as the latter only holds at limits.)

In some sense how this proof works is to assume $\textsf{ZFC}$ 'in the background' then see which sets inhabit each level of the hierarchy (we know '*a priori*' that $\omega$ exists, what we're checking is whether it is in $V_{\alpha}$ or not): if this view is fine then it's clear enough how choice holds (take the choice set $\mathcal{C}$ for a set in $V_{\alpha}$ and note that its elements are all therefore from $V_{\beta}$ for $\beta < \alpha$, thus $\mathcal{C} \subset V_{\beta}$, and so $\mathcal{C} \in V_{\alpha}$).

Is this reasoning OK? The only alternative I can see is somehow giving the construction of $\mathcal{C}$ for an arbitrary set (which is a problem choice is there to solve in the first place$\ldots$

Comment: "Worldly cardinals and above" seems a bit misleading. Just "at worldly cardinals" is accurate.

Comment: (But yes, your reasoning looks right. I'm not sure what your misgiving is, but if it's that we need to assume choice in $V$, then don't worry, that's unavoidable.)

Comment: Fair enough -- have edited. Thanks for the comments